# Windows installer and setup.exe

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I've Visual Studio setup project for creating installation for my project. After build Visual Studio create two files: *.msi file and setup.exe file.
MSI file contain all project files, information about destination, registry entries, etc. Setup.exe just bootstrapper for running msi file, but end-user is able run only msi file without setup.exe and program will be installed correctly. 
What setup.exe do? Should we run installer only using setup.exe or we can distribute our product without setup.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup .MSI version is enough.

Check this other post.

[What are the benefits of a MSI installer over a standard setup.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976241/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-msi-installer-over-a-standard-setup-exe)

Best Regards

Comment: Thank you. Its a great description of my problem)