# Node.js Choose .msi or .exe

Tags: node.js

In [node.js](http://nodejs.org) website is possible to download both `.exe` or `.msi` package for Windows, but `.exe` seems to simply open a command prompt shell.

What is difference between two packages, and how to choose between them?

I did not find this answer anywhere.

Comment: One is an installer(.msi) and one is a binary(.exe). The installer installs the binary along with some other things such as NPM and adds it to your PATH.

Comment: I thought about `.exe` "_include_" `.msi`, like describe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789530/what-are-the-specific-differences-between-msi-and-setup-exe-file). Instead, I obtain only a shell without any installation process, launching `.exe`

Comment: That's because the `.exe` is a binary and not an installer...

Comment: I prefer neither - if I have it installed somewhere I just create a zip version for Windows and adjust the paths/variables.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times the `.msi` package is just a wrapper for the `.exe` used for deployment via enterprise infrastructure like active directory.

There are diffrences in the internal structures boiling down to the point, that `.msi`is the file format for windows installations where `.exe` can just be any executable.

To be more precise here - the `.msi` takes advatege of the WindowsInstaller API where an .exe usually don't.

Further reading [Windows application installer frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284825/windows-application-installer-frameworks)

Comment: I'm sorry but in [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789530/what-are-the-specific-differences-between-msi-and-setup-exe-file) is written: "_A setup.exe may either be a bootstrapper or a non-msi installer. A non-msi installer will extract the installation resources from itself and manage their installation directly. A bootstrapper will contain an MSI instead of individual files. In this case, the setup.exe will call Windows Installer to install the MSI._" It seems the opposite concept. Am I wrong?

Comment: @LucaDetomi They're talking about setup executable files, not executable files in general. The node `.exe` file is NOT a setup file, it's a compiled Windows binary.

Comment: @LucaDetomi You can have a .exe calling a msi or the underlaying system calls. The point is that .msi relies on the Microsoft Host and makes mostly api calls where the .exe is handling the file copy and the registration by itself. You can Imagen an msi file more like a script than an acctual executabel

Comment: Ok, so.... what to choose for this particular behaviour in Node.js? You explained me differences, but in which case I should choose node.js msi installer, and otherwise in which one I should choose exe package?

Comment: Well If you intend to have node.js rolled out on diffrent workstations you would choose to get the .msi and if you need change some settings inside the .msi file. For a single install you typically choose the exe package, but the msi file would work just as well

Comment: I need to downgrade the node version. I installed latest (at this time) 6.6.0 and it has problems with the Webstorm. My colleagues are using 5.x and no problems with them. I found all versions on the node web site, but they are all *.exe. If I uninstall the current node... how do I install the older version, if it is coming only in the *.exe format?